# Add Required Anti-Forgery Field Ajax Request on MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do an ajax post request on my MVC app, simply post data of form to server.

but I always get this **error**:

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

This is my code for **ajax request**:

```
var reservationID = document.getElementById('ReservationID').value;
var arrival = document.getElementById('Arrival').value;
var departure = document.getElementById('Departure').value;
var noofrooms = document.getElementById('NoOfRooms').value;
var guestid = document.getElementById('GuestID').value;
var rateid = document.getElementById('RateID').value;
var agencyid = document.getElementById('AgencyID').value;
var sourceid = document.getElementById('SourceID').value;
var reservationtype = document.getElementById('ReservationType').value;
var reservation = { ReservationID: reservationID, Arrival: arrival, Departure: departure, NoOfRooms: noofrooms, GuestID: guestid, RateID: rateid, AgencyID: agencyid, SourceID: sourceid, ReservationTypeID: reservationtype };       
var url = '/Reservations/Create';

$.ajax({
    url: url,            
    type: "POST",
    data : reservation,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

How can I add this anti-forgery field on my ajax?

Answer (score 0):

For me this sollution works:

```
<script>
@functions{
    public string TokenHeaderValue()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
    }
}

$.ajax("api/values", {
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {  }, // JSON data goes here
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
    }
});
</script>
```

taken from:
[Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Attacks in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks)